Meaning of "折柳" in 李白's poem《春夜洛城闻笛》
In this well-known poem by 李白 (Li Bai):

《春夜洛城闻笛》
谁家玉笛暗飞声,
散入春风满洛城。
此夜曲中闻折柳,
何人不起故园情。

what is the meaning of "折柳"?
Is "snapped willow" an acceptable translation? Can it be interpreted as a metaphor of the poet's feelings ("something got broken deeply inside me", "I feel a crack in my soul")?

As explained at https://www.gushiwen.cn/shiwenv_be1894114330.aspx:

《春夜洛城闻笛》译文

这是从谁家飘出的悠扬笛声呢？它随着春风飘扬，传遍洛阳全城。
在客居之夜听到折(杨)柳的曲子，谁又能不生出怀念故乡的愁情？

折柳：即《折杨柳》笛曲，乐府“鼓角横吹曲”调名，内容多写离情别绪。曲中表达了送别时的哀怨感情。

"折柳" is abbreviated from the flute music named "折杨柳", which expresses the emotions of separation. In the poem, the flute music (笛曲 - 折杨柳), that Li Bai heard(聞), induced the remembrance of his hometown (while he was in a place away from home).

笛曲(flute music); "折杨柳" is the name of a flute music. In the poem, 杨 was omitted to satisfy the form of the particular poem style (7 letters per phrase). Note, 柳 = 杨柳 - willow.

The thing is, beginners in Chinese language do not normally analyze classical poetry?, just as beginners of the English language do not normally read Shakespeare?

What do willows do best? They bend and droop!
折腰：bow, bend at the waist
折杨柳: bent willow trees
译文
Translation
阵阵悠扬的笛声，是从谁家中飘出的？
(A) burst of melodious flute sound, wafts from whose house abroad?
随着春风飘扬，传遍洛阳全城。
Upon the spring breeze fluttering, it spreads throughout the whole city of 洛阳.
就在今夜，听到令人哀伤的《折杨柳》，
Then, on this eventide, hearing (the) plaintive sound of (the melody) 《折杨柳》,
有谁的思乡之情不会油然而生呢？
In whom will not arise a yearning for their home?
